# IList<string> to string by String.Join

Tags: c#

I have a list IList and I want to join all strings, i use that code but the result is :

```
Roles = String.Join(",",_userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)).
```

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1+d__112

I fix it by this code:

```
var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

var role = "";

foreach (var r in roles)
{
    if (!role.Contains(",")) { role = r; }
    else { role = "," + r; }
}
vm.ApplicationUser = user;
vm.Roles = role;
```

I want to know why the first code doesn't work.

Comment: Because you need to wait for the `Task`.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
Roles = String.Join(",", await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user))
```

Comment: Ensuring that the method that you've called this in returns a task and is itself marked as async.